# SharePoint Online Recycle Bin Copy/Backup

Tags: sharepoint, backup, sharepoint-online

This might be a odd question but is it possible at all to make a backup or copy of my Recycle Bin, if not possible no worries.

Reason for asking : Some people deletes file and remembers 100days later they accidently deleted the file, then it's a bit harder to get back the file just from restoring the file from the recycle bin.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that using CSOM or SSOM. 
CSOM:
From code you can access Web.RecycleBin property that is collection of type RecycleBinItemCollection.

Comment: Thanks for the info,much appreciated. Is there a website where I can get more info or just google it and work from there.